# Consumed resources in azure

Tags: azure

Where can I see the resources I've been consumed (like hours of processing, bandwidth, etc ... ) in windows azure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_CostManagement/Menu/overview

This option is general at the end of your home panel, the very last one. this is probably the reason you didn't see it